# How to use put var between double quotes

Tags: php, performance, double, quotes

I want to use this code

```
$person = ""$steamid" "" "abcdefghijklmnopqrstu" "ce"\n";
```

for example if `$steamid` = STEAM_0:0:123456

the outpur should look like this
"STEAM_0:0:123456" "" "abcdefghijklmnopqrstu" "ce"

I hope someone can correct my PHP code

```
$person = ""$steamid" "" "abcdefghijklmnopqrstu" "ce"\n";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use . (dot) between variables to join them.

Example:

```
$var = $somevar . "sometext" . $anothervar . "and it works" . "you can add more text";
```

Spaces doesn't matter between variables and quoted text.

Explanation:

There are two string operators. The first is the concatenation operator ('.'), which returns the concatenation of its right and left arguments. The second is the concatenating assignment operator ('.='), which appends the argument on the right side to the argument on the left side.

```
<?php
    $a = "Hello ";
    $b = $a . "World!"; // now $b contains "Hello World!"

    $a = "Hello ";
    $a .= "World!";     // now $a contains "Hello World!"
?>
```

**Here is detailed explanation of same thing from [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)**

And to answer your question, since you need to output these -> " " , you need to use single quotation marks in code. So, your code would look like this:

```
<?php

    $steam = '"STEAM_0:0:123456"'; 
    echo $person = $steam . ' ""' .' "abcdefghijklmnopqrstu" "ce"';

?>
```

**Here are screenshots:**

[image: Code]

and

[image: output]

Comment: Why should the OP "use .(dot)"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Ok. Sure I will explain that. Thanks for pointing out that.

Comment: can you do it for me ?

Comment: i want the output to look like this  
"STEAM_0:0:123456" "" "abcdefghijklmnopqrstu" "ce"

Comment: $steam = "STEAM_0:0:123456";

echo $person = $steam . " abcdefghijklmnopqrstu ce";

I think, this works. If this is not what you are asking for.. you need to give more info on your question. or explain it a little bit more.

Comment: @AminHijaz Edited my answer. Check out.

Comment: thanks very much <3

Answer (score 4):

standard practices to use variable in double quote.

```
$person = "{$steamid} abcdefghijklmnopqrstu ce\n";
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: yes it's strange now.

Comment: Not important, but you are missing some of the OP's data at the end...

Comment: ... technically it's just missing the space before the "ce" I think

Comment: @CD001 And the new line :-) But you are partly right, I didn't even notice the `ce` because of the missing space...

Comment: Just edited it to be specific to the desired output - the method was sound.

Comment: @CD001 I agree, that's why I upvoted. It was just a small detail, not important, like I mentioned...

Comment: STEAM_0:0:123456abcdefghijklmnopqrstuce
if i do your code it will look like this

Comment: "STEAM_0:0:123456" "" "abcdefghijklmnopqrstu" "ce"
i want it like this :) thanks

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to concatenate php variable and string. you can do like this:

You can use .(dot) to concatenate multiple string (also php variables) as described below.

```
$person = $steamid."abcdefghijklmnopqrstu"."ce"."\n";
```

Comment: "STEAM_0:0:123456" "" "abcdefghijklmnopqrstu" "ce" i want the output look like this thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

- **first method** :- $person = `"{$var1} abc {$var2}"`;
- **second method** :- $person =`$var1."abc".$var2`

Comment: i know thats i want quotes in output  
"STEAM_0:0:123456" "" "abcdefghijklmnopqrstu" "ce" like this :) thanks for help